# R - Vlookup element from a data.frame to multiply with data from another data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, vlookup

Maybe it is an easy question, but it usually happens that simple things in other languages turn out to be not so easy in R. I've tried, but i could't find a solution. Can anyone help me with this?

I've got one data frame, that it could be:

Prod      Time                Price1
A               2017-01-31     10.000
A               2017-02-28     12.800
A               2017-03-31     15.300
B               2017-01-31     11.000
B               2017-02-28     12.000
B               2017-03-31     12.200
C               2017-01-31     11.000
C               2017-02-28     11.600
C               2017-03-31     12.000

and another one, that could be like this:

Time                  EUR_USD_Rate
2017-01-31         1.200
2017-02-28         1.214
2017-03-31         1.216

I want to divide every Price1 by every EUR_USD_Rate according to the TIME rate.

I don't want to merge data.frames.

I want to apply this in an shiny app. I want it to plot a dispersion plot with the Price1 divided by de EUR/USD Rate. So I simply want to call the EUR/USD rate to tell ggplot2 to plot Price1 divided by EUR/USD. Does anyone can help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You said you don't want to merge data sets?  What do you mean by this?  Why this constraint?

Comment: It is for a shiny app that plot using ggplot. It is a little change triggered by a selectinput control, so i don't want to change all my main data frame for a simple selectinput selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closest equivalent of vlookup in R would be [`match`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html).

To lookup the conversion rate for a specific date, you can do

```
df2$EUR_USD_Rate[match(df1$Time,df2$Time)]
```

Which can loosely be explained as; find the indices where I can find `df1$Time` in the vector `df2$Time`, and use those to subset from `df2$EUR_USD_Rate`.

So you can adjust prices with the statement:

```
df1$Price_adjusted = df1$Price/df2$EUR_USD_Rate[match(df1$Time,df2$Time)]
```

Output (using the data supplied by Austin Springer):

```
  Prod       Time Price Price_adjusted
1    A 2017-01-31  10.0       8.333333
2    A 2017-02-28  12.8      10.543657
3    A 2017-03-31  15.3      12.582237
4    B 2017-01-31  11.0       9.166667
5    B 2017-02-28  12.0       9.884679
6    B 2017-03-31  12.2      10.032895
7    C 2017-01-31  11.0       9.166667
8    C 2017-02-28  11.6       9.555189
9    C 2017-03-31  12.0       9.868421
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't want to merge the data frames... but doing exactly that makes for a very simple solution by changing the dataset before feeding it to `ggplot`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- merge(df1, df2)[order(Product)]
df1[, Price1 := Price1 / EUR_USD_Rate]
df1[, EUR_USD_Rate := NULL]
df1
         Time Product    Price1
1: 2017-01-31       A  8.333333
2: 2017-02-28       A 10.543657
3: 2017-03-31       A 12.582237
4: 2017-01-31       B  9.166667
5: 2017-02-28       B  9.884679
6: 2017-03-31       B 10.032895
7: 2017-01-31       C  9.166667
8: 2017-02-28       C  9.555189
9: 2017-03-31       C  9.868421
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, snoram! But the point is I want to avoid merging. df2 is going to change frenquetly and this is only going to be triggerd by checkbox in a shiny app. I don't want to touch df1, which is a big data base, i would only like a vlookup in xls, but in R.

Answer (score 0):

David, I often have the same problem since I originally come from a .net/sql background.  That is why I leaned on that to accomplish what I believe you're asking for.  The last column in dfFinal should be what you need if I understand you correctly.

```
c1=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C');
c2=c('2017-01-31','2017-02-28','2017-03-31','2017-01-31','2017-02-28','2017-03-31','2017-01-31','2017-02-28','2017-03-31');
c3=c(10.000,12.800,15.300,11.000,12.000,12.200,11.000,11.600,12.000);
df1 = data.frame(Prod=c1, Time=c2, Price=c3);df1;
df2 = data.frame(Time=c('2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31'), EUR_USD_Rate=c(1.200, 1.214, 1.216));df2;

library(sqldf);
dfFinal = sqldf("
        select 
          d1.* 
          ,d2.EUR_USD_Rate
          ,d1.Price/d2.EUR_USD_Rate as RESULT
        from 
          df1 d1
          left join df2 d2
            on d1.Time = d2.Time
  ");
dfFinal;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Austin! I think that would be the same as doing a "merge" in R. The df2 is going to change freuquently, so the point is avoiding merging every time df2 changes. Besides, There is going to be a checkbox in a shiny app, so merging or making another dataframe would delay the output. I would a simple vlookup in xls, but in R.